# Joining form and subform/appending columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form, a subform, and 3 tables. The first table is the data in the form, simple stuff like date, and the name of the person entering the form. The second table is the subform which is a list of tasks and a yes/no button next to it stating whether the task has been completed.

I would like the form to fill the third table so that for each observation in the subform, you have the name of the task from the subform, the yes/no button from the subform, plus the date, and name of person from the form. So if there are ten tasks, and one person does them all then I'd want the new table to have ten observations that each has the person's name, the date, the name of the task, and whether it was done. The problem is to join the first two tables into the third would require some common variable to join on and that's not really what I want. It's more like appending columns.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Currently, is there any relationship between the form and subform? If there is, then you don't need a third table unless there is additional data to capture (that you didn't mention)?

Comment: There is no relationship between the form and subform.

Comment: The idea is that the person fills out the form information about themselves and the date, and then fills out the subform saying which tasks they've completed. I'd like to then have a third table that lists all the tasks, the data and name of the person, and whether they did the task. So if they form has been filled out 3 times by 3 different people there would be 30 rows 10 for each person date stating whether they did that task.

Comment: Then I would add a button on the form named "Update". Add VBA code so that it performs some basic edits (user name & date; did they complete anything; etc.); then write the info to your third table. Is this basically what you want? BTW, if your subform is bound to the table of tasks, and a user clicks yes/no, it will update the table. Therefore you will need to handle that either by code that resets all flags to 'No' or some other method.